# NullPointerException and IllegalArgumentException when trying to load images in Java

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I have looked all over StackOverflow trying to find a solution for this but it's just kicking my ass. I have to remake Space Invaders for a class project and I need to load in the images (.gif files) using ImageIO.

I have all of my images and sound files in the source folder as shown below.

[class structure](https://imgur.com/a/JLc14)

Whenever I use `new File(/SItop0.gif")`, it gives me an IIOException. Why can't I load my images in?

Here is my code:

```
public BufferedImage getImage() {
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(/SItop0.gif")); // Line 30: this is the same for SITop, SIMiddle, and SIBottom. I'm just getting different images for each.
        return image;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

That is in the class for the object I want to draw on the panel, and the code below is in the class for the panel in which I call the method:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            if(i == 0) {
                SITop invader = new SITop();
                g.drawImage(invader.getImage(), 75+35*j, 80+25*i, null);
            }
            if(i == 1 || i == 2) {
                SIMiddle invader = new SIMiddle();
                g.drawImage(invader.getImage(), 75+35*j, 80+25*i, null);
            }
            if(i == 3 || i == 4) {
                SIBottom invader = new SIBottom();
                g.drawImage(invader.getImage(), 75+35*j, 80+25*i, null); // Line 42
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
at SIBottom.getImage(SIBottom.java:30)
at SIPanel.paintComponent(SIPanel.java:42)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

EDIT:

I changed the line to `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("Assets/SItop0.gif"));` and changed the method to overwriting the paintComponent and now it opens up the frame and the panel but it doesn't seem to draw anything. The screen is just black.

EDIT 2:

Changed the code in my question to coincide with the code I'm using now.

Comment: Where is your `Assets/SItop0.gif` located?

Comment: You’re getting the IllegalArgumentException because the image doesn’t exist where you think it does. According to your code, the image is stored in the Assets directory relative to the package of the class trying to load the image. Also, it’s case sensitive

Comment: Also, if you’re calling getGraphics on a Component based class, then you’re performing painting wrong

Comment: Which line is line 23 in SI.java?

Comment: My assets folder is not in the same package as the classes are in. I'm going to try moving it and seeing if that works. Also, how would you do it? I'm new to painting and I haven't found a lot of great tutorials.

Comment: I moved the assets folder and overwrote the paintComponent method instead. Now I'm only getting a black screen.

Comment: `getClass().getResource("Assets/SItop0.gif")` is relative to the current class.. You probably want `getClass().getResource("/Assets/SItop0.gif")` (note the leading '/'), if your "Assets" folder is in a different source root. Or, if "Assets" itself is a source root, you want simply `getClass().getResource("/SItop0.gif")`.

Comment: None of those worked. I'm getting a different error now, `IIOException: can't read file!` It says it is occurring on the line `BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("/SIbottom.gif"));` This line is identical within each of my SITop, SIMiddle, and SIBottom classes. They all use the same getImage() method, just with different images. However, in the overwritten paintComponent() method, I definitely get the images for the top and middle invaders first, because I need to draw them first, and the error doesn't happen until I get to that line.

Comment: I modified the original question to reflect the new error I'm getting.